# AWS Athena querying mixed JSON objects that have some moved to Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-glacier

I've got an Athena table pointed to a list of JSON objects akin to:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `example_table` (
`foo` struct<
  `bar`: string>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'ignore.malformed.json' = 'true'
)
LOCATION 
  's3://bucket/json';
```

This bucket has a lifecycle policy so that files of a certain age go to Glacier. I would like to query the other files, but see the following error:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
The operation is not valid for the object's storage class (
   Service: Amazon S3; 
   Status Code: 403; 
   Error Code: InvalidObjectState;
```

AWS claims to ignore Glacier objects per this update (2/2019): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2019-02-18.html

I don't get access denied, but rather InvalidObjectState. How can I create a table to query these JSON files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your objects Glacier or Glacier Deep Archive. Seems the storage class of `DEEP_ARCHIVE` is not ignored.

Are you or is there anyway you can structure your key to use a date time format i.e. `2020/05/14/blob.json`. If you can do this then you can partition your data which would stop you using data that has been modified by the lifecycle rule.

*Additional URLs*

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html

Comment: This was correct - we had our objects in Glacier Deep Archive. Thanks!